# To put a "pay for"

Tags: phrases

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/under-biden-democrats-poised-raise-150738436.html) there is a line saying,

> “I think what you’re going to see is the administration is going to **put a pay-for on the table** for at least some and maybe all of the infrastructure plan,” said Sen. Tim Kaine, D-Va. “If Team Biden makes a proposal, I’m sure we’ll make adjustments, but that’s a good way to start.”

Does that mean, considering the previous line, which says,

> Aides suggest his proposals might not be entirely **paid for,** with some one-time spending increases offset by increased federal borrowing.

Would that possibly mean Biden administration might need to issue bonds (borrowing)?

Comment: not refering to the language, but every single adminstration has issued bonds since ... long long ago.

Comment: @JamesK I know, lol but it seems reading the article Biden administration aka Democrats squeeze the entire or some of the spending by hiking the tax on very minority riches.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks and thank you for the answer :) in advance.

Comment: ha ha, very minority riches. You mean they should squeeze the rich for being too rich by making them pay their fair share of taxes.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not saying that. Democrats you elected is saying that. And I feel it's a good time. Especially Sanders and Elizabeth Wallen are hard on this.

Comment: Surely: hiking the tax on very minority riches.= increasing taxes on the minority of very rich people.

Comment: @Lambie Would you kindly read the article? Then you will (probably) understand me.

Comment: @Lambie The first line (Reading this article).

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Comment: Yeah, so it means that BIden is probably going to say: If you want X, you have to pay for it. But, the guy uses a kind of political speak so the meaning cannot be pinpointed 100%. That has nothing to do with bonds, this sentence.

Comment: @Lambie Okay...thanks.

Comment: It is extremely annoying when politicians speak that kind of double-speak where what they are saying is really not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe "**a pay-for**" is common English usage. Perhaps it is jargon or shorthand used by politicians involved in the budgeting process.

I think your interpretation is correct, considering the previous sentence: Senator Kaine is saying he believes the administration will have a plan to **pay for** most of the projects they are proposing (by way of increased taxes or other such fundraising measures). But the planned spending will not be covered (**paid for**) entirely, so the government will have to borrow money to make up the difference.

Comment: Yes, "cover" will be clearer. Thank you.